# Writing inside a cursor android

Tags: android, android-cursor

while reading the documentation on `Cursor` [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) I read that cursor provides read/write access. I had gone through the API methods of `Cursor` but there is no setter method available to write into the `Cursor`. It would be of great help if you could provide me with code snippet. Thanks in advance

Comment: Huh, indeed it says so. Never heard of any setters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a bug in the documentation. You are quite right that there are no `Cursor` methods to modify the underlying data.

If you do try to modify the underlying data (by executing SQL statements, for example) while iterating over the data using a `Cursor`, bad things happen. If you need to make changes, you should keep a separate record of what you need to change whilst iterating with the `Cursor`, and then apply those changes separately once the `Cursor` is safely closed.